# Append Multiples of Squares of integers greater than 2 and sort them

Tags: python, numbers, sequence

For Example :

```
4,8,9,12,16,18,.......
```

How can we do this for big size array?
The basic one I made, took a lot of time to execute :

```
for i in range(1,1000):
    for j in range(2,1000):
        l.append((i)*((j)*(j)))
s=set(l)
l1=list(s)
l1.sort()
print(l1)
```

Size of list should be in order of 10^6.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Nested loops in i and j up to 1000, and then i.j.j Converted to set, then converted back to list and finally sorted them.

Comment: Please add your code to your question and mention exactly what you expect in the output!

Comment: I have Edited the Question.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote your code in a more better way:

```
my_list = sorted([i*(j**2) for i in range(1, 1000) for j in range(2, 1000)])
```

However, what you are asking is execution time which for this operation takes a fraction of seconds (around 1.5 second) and what you are seeing is printing time which in different editors and interfaces is different. For example I ran this script in *sublime text* it took almost 9 minutes while it took 1.4 minute in *command line*.

if you check the length of your list:

```
print len(sorted([i*(j**2) for i in range(1, 1000) for j in range(2, 1000)]))
```

you will see, to print a list with 997002 elements, obviously you should consider an execution time.
Another factor which you should take into account is [the Big-O Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) which in your case called O(n^2) notation and this run time will exponentially increase if you increase the number of loops.

Comment: Yeah, but there must be some efficient way to deal with this.